# Недокошен / не докошен

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Луг был мною недокошен / не докошен.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Значение действия.** Краткие причастия, а также причастия при наличии зависимых слов пишутся с НЕ раздельно:

*Луг был **мною не докошен**. Сегодня постараюсь закончить работу.*

**2. Качественный признак.** Растения не полностью покошены.

*Луг **был недокошен**, кое-где торчали островки травы и луговых цветов.*

**[Недокошенный луг](https://bigdevops.ru/article/nedokoshen-eto-ponyatie-kotoroe-obychno-ispolzuetsya-v-selskom-hozyaystve-ili-sadovodstve-i-oznachaet-to-chto-trava-ili-rasteniya-ne-byli-polnostyu-pokosheny-ili-podstrizheny-eto-sostoyanie-mozhet-nablyudatsya-naprimer-v-koshennyh-luzhaykah-gde-ostalis-nerovnosti-ili-vytyanutaya-trava)**

Термин используется в сельском хозяйстве или садоводстве и означает то, что трава или растения не были **полностью** покошены или подстрижены. Это состояние может наблюдаться, например, в кошенных лужайках, где остались **неровности или вытянутая трава.**

Недокошенность может быть вызвана **несколькими причинами.** Во-первых, это может быть связано с **неправильной** работой садового инструмента, такого как газонокосилка.

Во-вторых, **особенности местности** могут привести к недокошенности. Если на участке есть неровности, выпуклости или вытяжки, то косилка может пропустить эти участки или не достичь травы в них. Также, ветки деревьев или другие препятствия могут помешать полному покосу травы.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно с ***не*** писать раздельно: *Луг был мною **не** докошен.*

*Доко́шенный* — страдательное причастие прошедшего времени от глагола "докосить" (*докошен* — краткая форма).

Правило Розенталя ([§70. Правописание ***не*** с причастиями](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#%D0%B7_08)):

> **3.** Пишется раздельно ***не*** с краткими причастиями, например: *рукопись **не отредактирована**, цитаты **не проверены**, работа **не выполнена***.

*Бросая пригоршни горошин,

Дождь барабанит по стеклу.

**Мой луг вчера был не докошен**,

Сегодня — снова не смогу...*
Александр Суханевич. Опоздание